# why does my accordion have gaps and are spaced even tho I put margin and padding 0px

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Hi im making a website for my church out of Bootstrap and making that into Wordpress.. I wanted to know why my accordions are like this when I separated all my Wordpress files.

[image]

**The blue bars should be touching and it shouldn't be that thick where it leaves space under and over the headings in the accordions.**

suppose to look like this:[image]

Here are all my css on the accordion:

```
 .accback {
     margin-top:-20px;

     }

 .accordion-inner ul li {
     list-style:none;
     line-height:35px;
     color:black;


     }

 .accordion-toggle {
     color:white;
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
     border:0px;
 }
 .accordion-toggle a {
     color:white;
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
     border:0px;
 }

 .accordion-heading{
      padding:0px;
     margin:0px;
     border:0px;
     }

     .accordion-group{
         padding:0px;
     border:0px; 

         }
  .accordion {
     margin:auto;
     padding:50px 20px 40px 20px;
     max-width:500px;
     border:0px;
 }
```

And here is my accordion:

```
 <div class="hidden-desktop container">
    <div class="accback">
   <div class="accordion text-center" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading btn-primary">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">Events<div class="pull-left"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
       <ul>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
      <li>Instagram</li>
      <li>LinkIn</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading btn-primary">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo"><div class="icon-chevron-down icon-white pull-left"></div>
        Schedule
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <ul>
      <li>(818)111-1111</li>
        <li>(818)222-2222</li>
         <li>(818)333-3333</li>
          <li>(818)444-4444</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading btn-primary">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree"><div class="icon-chevron-down icon-white pull-left"></div>
       Worship Night
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
      <ul>
      <li>
       blah blah blah blah blah
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading btn-primary">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour"><div class="icon-chevron-down icon-white pull-left"></div>
        Follow Us
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
       <ul>
      <li>Facebook</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
      <li>Instagram</li>
      <li>LinkIn</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div><!---Background of Accordions--->
   </div>
```

Comment: can u share your code in Jsfiddle?

Comment: not really because it's all in seperate .php files for Wordpress but heres the website http://ichurchinla.com/

Comment: I cant put it in JSfiddle because it's all in separate .php files and thats when the problem occurred.. if it were to be a regular .html file it works fine but when I put it in as separate .php files it did this.

Comment: i cant see that accordion on the website provided?

Comment: thats because its for mobile you have to shrink your window size

Answer (score 2):

your code is working fine in my browser.

Perhaps it is taking space from other css file. Please try it in separate file.

Or find from where it is taking space and remove it.